# React private route is not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I got headache trying to figure out why private route is not redirecting to the path I've setting up. I think a miss something but I don't know what. 
Did someone help me figure out ?

here is my private route component :

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../../context/auth/Authcontext';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const {isAuthenticated, loading} = authContext;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
          <Redirect to='/pagelist' />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I'm using context to handle all the authentification part.What I'm trying to do is if you are not logging you can't access the the dashboard.

here is my App.js :

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from './components/layouts/Navbar';
import Dashboard from './components/pages/Dashboard';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';

import AuthState from './context/auth/AuthState';
import AlertState from './context/alert/AlertState';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';


if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <AlertState>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='container'>
              <Alerts />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </AlertState>
    </AuthState>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I think I did everything correctly because when I'm watching in my console, current user are not authenticated but the dashboard is still accessible. Did I miss something ?

Comment: did you wrap your app in AuthContext.Provider?

Comment: hey, take a look to my react console. Here is a screenshot https://ibb.co/6ZN8TnQ  .

Comment: Maybe there is an auth token in the local storage, and your application automatically sets the user logined. If the app has such logic, can you check localStorage?

Comment: Nothing in the local storage. I've deleted everything before try again something. 
But  by initiating token ``` const {token} = authContext; ``` in my private route file and changed  <..!isAuthenticated && !loading..> with only <!token >,, everything works fine. 
 
The problem seems to be isAuthenticated && loading but why it is not working with them ?

Comment: Can you share AuthContext, AuthState and setAuthToken  code?